# Existence of efficiently computable integrals for "spiky" functions

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, integration

$\DeclareMathOperator\spikify{spikify}$*Apologies if I'm misusing the word spiky, I mean it only as a visual description of a function, not in any technical mathematical sense!*

We define the function
$\spikify(n, c, y) = \begin{cases}
        y & n=0 \\
        c^{\spikify(n-1, c, y)} & n > 0 \\
    \end{cases}
$

Thus

$\spikify(1, c, y) = c^y$

$\spikify(2, c, y) = c^{(c^y)}$

$\spikify(3, c, y) = c^{(c^{(c^y)})}$
and so on

Can there exist a constant $c > 1$ such that:
for all functions $f$ where

- $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
- $f$ is continuous over the domain $[0:1]$
- $f$ has a global maximum and global minimum within that domain
- $f$ is differentiable
- $f(x)$ has an efficiently computable closed form integral $F(x)$

Then the integral:

$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \spikify(n, c, f(x)) dx \approx \spikify(n,c,\max_{x_1 < x < x_2} f(x))$ can be calculated (or numerically approximated) for fixed, large $n$ and $c$ in time polynomial relative to $\log(n+c+\max(f(x))$.

I suspect the answer is absolutely not, because if so I think I could binary search to global maxima of a somewhat arbitrary function within a closed domain. (Note that the integral of the spikified function will tend to be dominated by the spike of the maximum of $f$ for large $n$) But I honestly have no idea where to even start to disprove the existence of such a constant.

More generally, are there stronger restrictions on $f$ that would allow a closed form for integrals of "spikified" functions, or other variations of "spikifying" a function that would allow polynomial time approximation of an integral over a closed range, regardless of how spiky we chose to make the transformed function?